# Problem with adding UISearch bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement UISearch bar but I have some problems.
When app starts I add table view like this:

```
ChannelTableViewRootController *firstViewController = [[ChannelTableViewRootController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
    navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;

    UIView *uv = self.view;

    [uv addSubview:[navigationController view]];
```

I add UISearch bar in xib. Connect it to UISearchBar variable from my header file. Set delegate to self, and try to add it to header of tableview:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

And when I make object manually '`searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]init]; // + code from above`' I got displayed search bar like on image but nothing happends and can't put it over that header. I am trying to make search like in address book with scopes etc.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to create the searchbar with the initWithFrame. Try giving Values to it and adding subView to the view not on header. I think you have some mistake in positioning.

You also specified that you added UISearchbar in xib and also you have allocated in the coding also. Dont do that its a wrong way. Do any one of them i suggest you if you add tableView programatically then add searchbar programatically. Or assign them both in Xib.

Otherwise have a look at this tutorial

http://ved-dimensions.blogspot.com/2009/02/iphone-development-adding-search-bar-in.html

Comment: Thanks, now it looks better, that tutorial is great. I connected all to my application and it work, but just one thing is missing. In address book application, when user tap on search text field searchbox goes up in header and under search box appear folder list where search is possible. This is called scope or something, any advice on how to make this effect?